# Basic Serial Port Communication Visual Studio C++ (having trouble wading through existing examples)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, serial-port

I am just starting using C++, and I am having trouble figuring out how to send some information to my arduino (much easier to code) through a serial port.  The information is a RGB value that is read from my webcam using opencv.  This is what I have so far (someone helped me with this):

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/video/video.hpp>

int main()
{
int delay = 30; // 30 ms between frames
int x = 20; // X coordinate of desired pixel
int y = 140; // Y coordinate of desired pixel
int key = 0;
cv::VideoCapture camera(0);
cv::Mat img;
while(key != 27)
{
camera >> img;
cv::imshow("Web cam image", img);
cv::Vec3b pixel = img.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);

// Write the values of pixel to the serial port here 

key = cv::waitKey(delay);
}
return 0;
}
```

Everything I find online seems really complicated, and I have been trying to figure it out for a few hours now.  Is there way to do this that is not too complicated?

Comment: neither your question is related to opencv, nor is your code related to serial communication.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible for serial I/O on Windows to be very complicated but fundamentally it doesn't need to be - you just open the port, set your baud rate etc, and then write the data. Try something like this (obviously adjusting the COM port and parameters as you need):

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM1", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    DCB port{0};
    port.DCBlength = sizeof(port);
    if (GetCommState(hFile, &port)
    &&  BuildCommDCB("baud=19200 parity=N data=8 stop=1", &port)
    &&  SetCommState(hFile, &port))
    {
        DWORD written;
        // write the data - I'm assuming &pixel[0] will work for a cv vector
        // if not, you'll have to fix this bit yourself
        WriteFile(hFile, &pixel[0], 3, &written, NULL);
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}
```

Comment: I tried putting this where it says //Write the values of pixel to the serial port here.  That didn't work, is there a library that I need to include along with the code you posted?

Comment: My telepathy seems to be non-functioning today so I won't be able to help you I'm sorry.

Comment: do you want a screenshot?

Comment: Are you including <windows.h> anywhere? If not, try adding that.

Comment: That got rid of all but four of the errors.  Let me post a picture of it. http://imgur.com/UeavXW4

Comment: For both the `BuildCommDCB` and `CreateFile` calls, put an `L` in front of the string literal (e.g. `CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\COM1", ...`).

Comment: Okay, that let me build it.  However, when I run it, nothing is being sent to the com port.